# How to set uniqueness for a member of a class while inserting the class to Mongo DB in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to Java and I am writing code to insert a user class to MongoDB and retrieve data based on a unique user ID.
For that, I want to set userID as a unique value while inserting my class user into MongoDB.

my code snippet,

I have a user class with members

```
{
String userID,
String Name, etc
}
```

My add user function with db (as MongoDatabase instance injected) looks like

```
public String addUser(User user){
    ...
    MongoCollection<User> userCollection = db.getCollection(<collection_name>, User.class);
```

I am using MongoCollection<TDocument> interface to allow class as a data. As per the [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) mentioned in other Stackoverflow answers, I am trying to use CreateIndex() method as below

```
    userCollection.createIndex({"userID": 1 }, {unique : true});
    ...
}
```

But it's not working. showing syntax errors.

By using MongoCollection<Document> it might be possible but I wanted to check if it's possible with class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax appears to be for the MongoDb command line. Here's the javadoc for the MongoCollection class:
https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/latest/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html

This looks like what you're trying to use:

```java
java.lang.String createIndex(Bson keys,
                             IndexOptions indexOptions)
```

So `{"userID": 1 }` will need to be a Bson object, and `{unique : true}` will need to be an IndexOptions object.

Edit:
For example something like this:

```java
IndexOptions indexOptions = new IndexOptions().unique(true);  
collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("userID"), indexOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks @mswatosh for the reply, I tried this option. It's showing a syntax error for me.

Comment: Are you doing something like this? This is what using the java syntax should look like:

IndexOptions indexOptions = new IndexOptions().unique(true);
collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("userID"), indexOptions);

Comment: Yes @mswatosh exact solution I did implement and it worked for me... Anyways thanks a lot for your efforts.